# Haskell-Custom data types

Tags: haskell

I need some advice on how to return a list of chapter names that do not contain text blocks `(Text)` in their type list `[Article]`

```
data Article = Text String
             | Section String [Article] deriving (Show)

myArticle :: Article
myArticle = Section "Document" [
                 Section "Introduction" [
                       Text "My intoduction",
                       Section "Notation" [Text "alpha beta gamma"]],
                 Section "Methods" [
                       Section "Functional Programming" [Text "FPR"],
                       Section "Logical Programming" [Text "LPR"]],
                 Section "Results" [Text "All is great"]]
names :: Article -> [String]
```

Expected output:

```
names myArticle = ["Document", "Methods"]
```

I tried the basic functions:

```
names :: Article -> [String]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74572062/edit) your question to include your source code as a working [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be tested by others. As it stands you forgot to add your code, just a function signature isn't gonna cut it.

Comment: The sentence 'chapter names that do not contain text blocks (Text) in their type list [Article]' is not correct. There is no such thing as a type List, all elements in a Haskell list are of the same type, which is Article in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always start by observing the structure of your datatype:

```
                     Section
                   /        \
                Text        Section
                            /   |  \
                         Text Text  Text
```

You can see that this is a tree. Thus we start by deconstructing this tree in names:

```
names :: Article -> [String]
names a = case a of
  Text _ -> []
  Section chptr xs -> []
```

We only want to return `chptr` if none of it's childs in the list`xs` is text. Thus we need a function to know whether something is text:

```
isText :: Article -> Bool
isText (Text _) = True
isText _ = False
```

Now looking at `names` we can use the built-in `any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool` function to return chptr, if none of it's childs is text:

```
names :: Article -> [String]
names a = case a of
  Text _ -> []
  Section chptr xs -> 
    (if any isText xs then [] else [chptr])
```

But `names` only returns the first chapter name. We already concluded this is a tree, and processing these in Haskell is usually done recursively. So we must call names again on our list `xs` of sections, and add the result to the names we already found:

```
names :: Article -> [String]
names a = case a of
  Text _ -> []
  Section chptr xs -> 
    (if any isText xs then [] else [chptr]) ++ concatMap names xs
```

voila!